# guzzlehttp and symfony with rest api problem

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I want to make a post call with rest api using `guzzlehttp` in `symfony` ... 
I wrote this code but the response

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/")
 */
public function postAction()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'username' => 'test',
            'password' => 'test',
        ]
    ]);

    return $this->render('esterne/post.html.twig', array(
        'response'=>$response,
    ));
}
```

this is the twig file **post.html.twig**

```
{{response}}
```

the result is this:

```
{"status":"200","data":{"is_auth":true,"userToken":"194b873c004716acb3e0a5fba09fe405"}}
```

but if I put in html:

```
return $this->render('esterne/post.html.twig', array(
    'response'=>$response->getBody(),
));
```

it results in error 500 internal server error

> [2018-11-14 09:56:35] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string")." at /app/app/Resources/views/esterne/post.html.twig line 1 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string\"). at /app/app/Resources/views/esterne/post.html.twig:1, ErrorException(code: 0): Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string at /app/var/cache/prod/twig/47/478ca9f9b0a5c69caa7b0fed874bf831466230764635f396f057dc2c33868549.php:23)"} []

**SOLUTION**

use file

```
{{ response|json_encode()|raw }}
```

in twig and

```
return $this->render('esterne/post.html.twig', array(
    'response'=>json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), FALSE),
));
```

Comment: Convert your response  to json response .

Comment: like this ?? Creating a JSON Response¶
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try following response.

```
return $this->render('esterne/post.html.twig', array(
    'response'=>$response->getBody()->getContent(),
));
```

Comment: error... not work 2018-11-14T10:20:40.804640+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-14 10:20:40] php.CRITICAL: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::getContent() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream::getContent() at /app/src/AppBundle/Controller/EsterneController.php:109)"} []

Comment: `->getContents()` should be used instead of `->getContent()`

Comment: now no error.... but the result is not in json ... view source of the page is html
   {&quot;status&quot;:&quot;200&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;is_auth&quot;:true,&quot;userToken&quot;:&quot;9a1d168594a9755d849abe283b3505ea&quot;}}

Comment: you should be used instead of above.
json_decode($response->getBody(), true); or json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)

Comment: ok ... in both case the result is json but in the response appear Array ... why?

Comment: because response is array when use json decode with true. if you want json, which should use false. so you could see how usage.
http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: ok ... if i put false i have error 500 ... maybe the problem is the twig file?

Comment: i put in the twig {{ response|json_encode() }} works but the source of it ....
{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;200&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;is_auth&quot;:true,&quot;userToken&quot;:&quot;f22f310180b9984e8aee7df3e2ea2e0b&quot;}}

Comment: maybe work with this in twig file {{ response|json_encode()|raw }}